# how to add custom apache config to openshift.conf file in openshift?

Tags: apache, apache2, openshift

I am new to openshift and i am trying to customize apache config.

I want to add virtual host to openshift.conf.

```
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

Listen localhost:8080


<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName somehost

  ProxyPass / somehost:8000/ keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse / somehost:8000/


  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-HTTPS "0"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not add a virtual host to the apache config.  You would have to use the DIY cartridge or build a custom apache cartridge.  If you can give more details on what exactly you are trying to accomplish (looks like a reverse proxy of some type), then maybe we can offer a suggestion, also, we do not allow proxies on openshift.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I am trying to do reverse proxy. In background I am going to start mojolicious web server on port 8000 internally but I want to get request through apache web server because I am going to add web loadbalancer(HAProxy).

Comment: Why not just setup on port 8080, run a scaled application, and let our haproxy take care of the load balancing?

Comment: mojolicious is a perl framework which has its own webserver, so if we are using the framework we have to use the mojolicious webserver by default.

Comment: That's fine, have it run on port 8080 on one of the perl gears then?

Comment: do we have any way to do it?